# Spring boot webflux - Validating Configuration properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-validator

I am using Spring boot webflux 2.4.2.

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
```

**Property Class**

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;


    @Validated
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service")
    public class AppProperties {
    
        private String env;
        
        public String getEnvrironment() {
          return envrironment;
        }

        public void setEnvrironment(String envrironment) {
           this.envrironment = envrironment;
        }
    }


public enum Environments {
    
    DEV,
    UAT,
    PROD

}
```

**application.properties**

> service.environment= DEV

Here, I want to do the validation of environment property to be one of the enum value. Is there any Spring boot out of the box validation support for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot can bind straight to an enum for you. If you change the type of `AppProperties` `env` field to be `Environments`, Spring Boot will automatically enforce that the value of the `service.environment` property is one of the three values declared in your `Environments` enum. It also supports case insensitive binding so you could configure `service.environment=dev` and the value of `AppProperties`' `env` field would be set to `Environments.DEV`.